# Filter documents by nested entities in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

Consider following documents:

```json
[
  {
    "Book": "Book A",
    "Authors": [{"Name": "Author A", "Age": 25} , {"Name": "Author B", "Age": 27}]
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book B",
    "Authors": [{"Name": "Author C", "Age": 22} , {"Name": "Author D", "Age": 66}]
  },
  {
    "Book": "Book C",
    "Authors": [{"Name": "Author A", "Age": 25} , {"Name": "Author E", "Age": 46}, {"Name": "Author F", "Age": 88}]
  }
]
```

Now I want to query all books that has author name `Author A` or `Author D`. This is how I would create a query in mongodb flawor:

```js
db.collection("Books")
  .find({ "Authors": { "$elemMatch": { "Name" { "$in" : ["Author A", "Author D"] } } } })
```

Array where `$in` applies may be large enough (up to 100 entities) so ORing all varians isn't really feasible.

Is there any way this can be translated into graph query language?

```json
query {
  books(filter: ??? ) {
    name
  }
}
```

Important part is I do not own GQL server side and I'm only consuming an existing one

Comment: It looks like I need something like Hasura and GQL is not enough to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will get any book with Author A

```
db.collection("Books").filter(i => i.Authors.find(i => i.Name === "Author A"))
```